How can I dynamically display data in a column based on its columns?
I have two arrays of objects. The first array has the column names, the second has the table data. I want to display the data respectively. One of the objects contains 3 key-values, they display in the first three TableRows and I want them to display dynamically in column number three and four.
I want to display the second object of the rows array in columns three and four.
const columns = [
{id: 1, one: "one", two: "two", three: "three", four: "four"}
]

const rows = [
{id: 1, title: "dog", age: "2", name: "Buzzy"}
{id: 2, item: "laptop", data: "something", year: "1980"}
]

   <table>
      <thead>
          {columns.map((data) => (
            <tr key={data.id}>
             {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
               <th key={key}>{value}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((data) => (
          <tr key={data.id}>
              {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
              <td key={key}>{value}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>


Can you explain better how you want the final result to look? I'm not understanding when you say that you want 3 different values dinamycally in 2 columns.

@maxpsz Sure. For example, I have 5 columns. For the columns I have a separate array of objects, for the rows too. The problem is that the data for row does not always have 5 elements each (i.e. it will not spread over 5 columns). Some of them only have three or two. If they have fewer elements than there are columns, they will spread out in the first columns and what I want is to set them on the 3rd and 4th columns, not on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd

@Emm You'd be better to put that information into your question.

I'm not sure if you are able to change the columns data structure, or you are just receiving them like that.
In any case, I'm assuming we are on the second case, so my first suggestion is to manipulate that data to make it easier to handle. when rendering.
const columns = [
  { id: 1, one: 'one', two: 'two', three: 'three', four: 'four' },
];

const newColumns = Object.entries(columns[0]).map(([key, value]) => ({
  accesorKey: key.toString(),
  header: value.toString(),
}));

const rows = [
  { id: 1, title: 'dog', age: '2', name: 'Buzzy' },
  { id: 2, item: 'laptop', data: 'something', year: '1980' },
];

const newRows = rows.map((row) => ({
  id: row.id,
  one: row.title,
  two: row.name,
  three: row.age,
  four: row.year,
}));

function App() {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {newColumns.map((col) => (
            <th key={col.accesorKey}>{col.header}</th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {newRows.map((row) => (
          <tr key={row.id}>
            {newColumns.map((col) => (
              <td key={col.accesorKey}>{row[col.accesorKey] || '-'}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}


newColumns is an array of objects that represent each column.
accesorKey is the the key we will use to match a row field to a specific column.
header is the header label of that column.
newRows is an array of rows, where each field represent a column accesorKey.

Try this:

    const columns = [
    { id: 1, one: "one", two: "two", three: "three", four: "four" }
  ];

  const rows = [
    { id: 1, title: "dog", age: "2", name: "Buzzy" },
    { id: 2, item: "laptop", data: "something", year: "1980" }
  ];

  return (
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        {columns.map((col) => (
          <tr key={col.id}>
            {Object.values(col).map((value, index) => (
              <th key={index}>{value}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((row) => (
          <tr key={row.id}>
            {Object.values(row).map((value, index) => (
              <td key={index}>{value}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );

